# Ionic/AngularJS dependency injection - factory with return functions

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dependencies, factory, code-injection

I would like to inject all factories to my controllers using one name...so in order to do that, I did this:

```
.factory('Injection', ['ActionSheetFactory', 'ResourceFactory', 'ModalFactory', 'ResponseFactory',
        function (ActionSheetFactory, ResourceFactory, ModalFactory, ResponseFactory) {
            return {
                ActionSheetFactory: ActionSheetFactory,
                ResourceFactory: ResourceFactory,
                ModalFactory: ModalFactory,
                ResponseFactory: ResponseFactory
            }
        }])
```

And then in controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services'])

.controller('categoriesCtrl', ['Injection', function (Injection, $ionicActionSheet, $state) {

    Injection.ActionSheetFactory.action($ionicActionSheet, $state);        
    ...

}])
```

**Problem:**

My factories look like this:

```
 .factory('ActionSheetFactory', function () {
        return {
            action: function ($ionicActionSheet, $state) { ... }
            action2: function(){}
               }
         })
```

So I have several functions inside each defined factory. And once I try to get to it, I get error `Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`. How can I fix that?

Comment: There's no obvious problem with Injection itself, aside from incorrect annotation `['Injection', function (Injection, $ionicActionSheet, $state) {`. Angular DI is quite straightforward, seek the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Well even if I remove the annotations, or put them all in correct order, nothing happens. The problem is that factory returns more than one function, so it cannot resolve it for some reason...

Comment: There is no obvious reason why Injection.ActionSheetFactory can be undefined. Again, Angular DI is straightforward. You have syntax error in ActionSheetFactory, but it would cause the app to shut down, not to silently fail. It is not possible to figure out what's wrong from the code you've posted.